# Run one process through different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I've got some heavyweight process, which does some video processing. I would like run it (using `Process.Start()`) so it uses diffrent threads from a threadpool. Is it possible run one process within different threads?

Comment: Have you tried doing that? What have you come up with?

Comment: ffmpeg.exe works excellent. Now I would like run my own app

Comment: So you have a process, which would use threads (from threadpool) to start other processes and wait for them to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process was not built with multithreading in mind, then no, you can't force it to run in parallel.  Parallelism is explicitly defined in code and is not something that the host system can enforce.

Assuming that this is a data parallelism problem, you could start the EXE as separate processes across multiple threads.  You would need to write code to separate and merge your data before and after processing though.  Whether this is possible/viable depends entirely on the nature of the data.